# Unable to bind javascript variable to JSON object key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I am trying to add a value in place of json object key but it always returns variable name.
My Code:

```
var projectName='';
let tempArray=[];
let output={};        
for(i=0;i<myJsonArray.length;i++){
        name = myJsonArray[i].Project;
        tempArray.push(myJsonArray[i]);
    }
    output= {projectName :tempArray};
    console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

This returns a JSON as

```
{"projectName":[{"Day":"MON","Project":"ABC","Billing Rate":"xxx"},{"Day":"TUE","Project":"ABC","Billing Rate":"xyx"}]}
```

But I need something like this:

```
{"ABC":[{"Day":"MON","Project":"ABC","Billing Rate":"xxx"},{"Day":"TUE","Project":"ABC","Billing Rate":"xyx"}]}
```

Can someone help on what I am missing here.

Kind Regards.

Comment: `{projectName :tempArray}` Here `projectName` is the key and `tempArray` is the value. So if you need `{ "ABC": ...}`, it shoulfd be `{ "ABC": tempArray}`

Comment: `output= {[name] :tempArray};` probably [does](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) what you need.

Comment: You just want another propertyname? `output= {'ABC' :tempArray}`

Comment: The one-liner you are looking for is: `const output = Object.fromEntries(myJsonArray.map(i=>[i.Project, i]));`

Comment: @BeSterDevelopment Yes,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wrap the project name into `[]` that would help to make a value become a key

```js
var name = '';
let tempArray = [];
let output = {};
for (i = 0; i < myJsonArray.length; i++) {
  name = myJsonArray[i].Project;
  tempArray.push(myJsonArray[i]);
}
output = {
  [name]: tempArray
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(output));
```

*P/s: I don't see any `projectName` variable there, so I replace it by `name` instead.*

Comment: Please vote to close duplicates. This has been asked a million times.